# What is "keyline design"?

Tags: color, design-principles

I have a style guide that says I shouldn't use specific color in keyline design, What does that mean?

EDIT: The style guide defines colors, which are okay to use with keyline design, and some colors that are not.

Comment: Context would matter. A keyline is generally an outline.

Comment: We can't answer this as we don't know what the style guide is referring to, either. Any chance you can share the full text of that section? As Scott states, a Keyline is essentially a wireframe--colors aren't usually even a part of that.

Comment: Well, I just learned something. In geography/land management, "keyline design" means something very specific: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyline_design Any chance this style guide has to do with the design of maps?